# MySQL Query, catch IP Addresses

Tags: mysql

I have a database, with 2 different tables.
database01 > "friends" and "accounts"

If a User registers and has a REF, there will be created a special row in "friends" table. Its shows the REF1 ID and REF2 ID. Both ID are unique and find on table "accounts", there is also the IP Address for each ID.

I'm trying to create a mysql query, which catches the 2 ID's found on database01.friends row REF1 and REF2, then based to their ID, catch the IP Address from database01.accounts row web_ip, then COMPARE it, and if its same, show them. Like a SELECT query.

I tried it this way, but I think its not correct at all:

```
SELECT id, REF1, REF2 
from database01.friends 
WHERE "REF1" and "REF2" web_ip = web_ip (SELECT id, web_ip FROM `database01.accounts`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    F.ID,
    F.REF1,
    F.REF2
FROM FRIENDS F
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS A1 on A1.id = F.REF1
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS A2 on A2.id = F.REF2
WHERE A1.WEB_IP = A2.WEB_IP;
```